# File Write in resource folder in jar

Tags: java, file, jar, directory, writer

I've a resource folder(files) in my java swing project which contains a text file (users.txt), I'm reading and writing data into that text file.
When i export it as jar file, reading from that file is fine, **but writing in the file is problem.**
I'm reading from file this way

```
InputStream in1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/files/users.txt"); 
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
```

Reading is perfectly working fine in jar file
and **writing in the same file below code(which is problem for jar file)**

```
    File file = new File("src/files/users.txt"); 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
    fw.write(data+"\n");
    fw.close();
```

please help me out how can i write into the file in resource folder using jar file.
Thanks!

Comment: If the file is inside the jar you cannot update the file.

Comment: Resources should be considered read-only. In other words, writing to resources is not supported (even when _not_ packaged in a JAR file). Application data should be stored in some other location.

Comment: @Slaw is there any other way to keep track of data (read/write) in jar file without some database? Actually I'm writing some data and use/check it later.

Comment: Write it into a file in the file system

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already say, files in the JARs are considered read-only.

You have to create a file at some user or installation directory based location (or a location chosen by the user).

If you have pre-configured data you have at least 2 options:

- Ship the file along the JAR file using some kind of packaging tool (can also be a ZIP file). For ZIP files have a look at the Maven Assembly Plugin, if you're using Maven.
- Extract the file from the JAR.

For the latter use case I've written some utility classes:

```
public void extractResource(String resourcePathString, Path targetDirPath) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {  
    URI jarURI = JarFiles.getJarURI(SomeClassInTheJar.class);  
    try (FileSystem jarFS = JarFiles.newJarFileSystem(jarURI)) {  
        Path resourcePath = jarFS.getPath(resourcePathString);  

        CopyFileVisitor.copy(resourcePath, targetDirPath);  
    }  
}
```

With the help of [CopyFileVisitor](https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.1.1/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html) you can easily recursively extract/ add directories from/ to JAR or ZIP files, as CopyFileVisitor uses [PathUtils](https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.1.1/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/PathUtils.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-) and thus works across file systems.

[JarFiles.getJarURI](https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.1.1/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/JarFiles.html#getJarURI(java.lang.Class)) gets the JAR URI of a class.

For more information have a look at the tutorial: https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.1.1/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#ExtractJarResourceSample

The library is Open Source. You can get it from Maven Central:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```